# Show hidden elements from span class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the prices of the apartments shown within this link: https://www.luxahome.com/propiedades?arrival=01/02/2023&departure=28/02/2023&guests=2&idi=3

Under each class "allotjament" there is a span tag with the price information for each of the apartments . Using BeautifulSoup and following this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.luxahome.com/propiedades?arrival=01/02/2023&departure=28/02/2023&guests=2&idi=3")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.find('iframe', class_='icnea-iframe').attrs["src"]

r = s.get(f"{iframe_src}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('span', class_='preu'))
```

But I am getting in return the class with the price hidden, such as this:

```
<span class="preu">
                                                                {{ property.price | roundNumber }}<span class="euro">€</span>
</span>
```

How can I visualize the {{ property.price | roundNumber }} values hidden within the span tag?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can simulate these call with `requests` module:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url1 = 'https://luxahome.icnea.net/WebService.asmx/DailyAvailability'
api_url2 = 'https://luxahome.icnea.net/WebService.asmx/DailyRate'
payload1 = {
    "arrival": "01/02/2023",
    "departure": "28/02/2023",
    "language": "es",
    "people": 2
}
payload2 = {
    "arrival": "01/02/2023",
    "departure": "28/02/2023",
    "id": "xxx",
    "language": "es",
    "people": 2
}

data = json.loads(requests.post(api_url1, json=payload1).json()['d'])

for a in data['DailyAvailability']:
    payload2['id'] = a['lodging_id']
    prices = json.loads(requests.post(api_url2, json=payload2).json()['d'])
    print('{:<5} {:<32} {}'.format(a['lodging_id'], a['headline'], prices['DailyRate']['price']))
```

Prints:

```
1015  APARTAMENTO CLAUDIO COELLO II    7287.00
1026  APARTAMENTO COLUMELA I           9340.00
1038  APARTAMENTO HERMOSILLA I         6900.00
1046  APARTAMENTO - MANUEL SILVELA I   4582.00
1047  CASTELLÓ III                     5160.00
1051  APARTAMENTO ESPARTINAS I         6850.00
1053  APARTAMENTO GENERAL PARDIÑAS I   9545.00
1056  APARTAMENTO JUAN DE MENA I       6590.00
1057  APARTAMENTO - CLAUDIO COELLO V   14850.00
1061  APARTAMENTO AYALA I              5959.00
1062  APARTAMENTO SAN BERNARDO I       3618.00
```

Comment: This is great thank you! @andrej , where did you get the https://luxahome.icnea.net/WebService.asmx/DailyAvailability url from?